# how Wordnet can be transferred to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, wordnet, database

I want to have wordnet
 http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/current-version/
in mongodb as currently its not available in json format.
What can I do to import , restore in mongodb as its available in sql format.
I can have other dictionaries but I specifically  want wordnet.

Comment: Could you show the format of the file? Also, mongodb is NoSQL database, so I doubt SQL files will do...
I think the quicker way will be to write a parser and build your database that way.